# which GCP Compute Engine instance to use to build Docker image?

Tags: docker, build, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

which GCP Compute Engine instance Data Scientist use to build Docker images and push them on GCP Container Registry ?

1. I am not allowed to have Docker installed on my Laptop
2. I cannot build it on CloudShell because my image is too big (>5 GB)
3. I can do it on Debian/Unbuntu VM but I need to installed Docker (I need to reinstall SDK, to install Docker and add user)
4. I can do it on Container-Optimized OS VM but SDK (need to push the image on CP Container Registry) need to be installed as well as python 2

Is there another easier option with everything already pre installed (Docker and SDK) ? How people do that in general ? Is there other points I should take into account for making my choice of Compute Engine instance ?

Comment: People spend the time to install and set up everything. Google Cloud Build is a great service for building containers, but you still need Docker or equivalent to run and test your containers. If you are also a developer, then you need even more installed and set up. Given the vast array of options, ...

Comment: Great John, I thought Google Cloud Build  was building the image in my CloudShell. As you mention, I still need a place to run the container for the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Google [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker)

With it, you can build (among other things) a container image merely by providing a Dockerfile (and any source files).

The service will build your image and push it to Google Container Registry:

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker

Comment: This is a great solution for building images but as it was mentioned by John, I need a place to run and test the containers.

Comment: Cloud Build is an open-ended tool. You can include build tests, linting etc. In (`cloudbuild.yaml`) scripts. Once you've built an image with Cloud Build you could simply pull it to a Container OS instance or other VM on Compute Engine (with Docker Engine) and perform arbitrary tasks there. You don't need to install Docker Engine locally.

Comment: Thanks for these info. It is exactly what I wanted to do. I will follow your suggestions.

Comment: You could even deploy the image to a GCE instance from Cloud Build ;-) Email me (@google.com) if you encounter challenges. I'm happy to help!